# switching between activities in java eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I have an app where there is a temperature converter on the page and once this is used there is a button to switch to a new activity. However when i click on the button to change to the second activity on the emulator nothing happens?

```
package com.example.assignment2project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText text;

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondScreen.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    // This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
    // "OnClick property" of the button
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
                if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                     fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                     celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    // Converts to celsius
    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }

    // Converts to fahrenheit
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have an `onCreate`1 method and an `onCreate` method. Android just calls the `onCreate` method, and not `onCreate1`. You need to rename `onCreate1` to `onCreate` and delete the other onCreate to get it to work.

Edit : And use `@Override` annotation over the new `onCreate`

Comment: & use `@Override` notation to check. ;)

Comment: Ok thanks will try, does this mean that you can only use one button on each activity? as i have two but you can only use one on create?

Comment: Cheers bro it worked! but what about the other button as this now shuts down the app instead of calculating the temperature in either celcius or fahrenheit

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
      next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, SecondScreen.class);
              startActivity(myIntent);
          }

      });
```

put this on your oncreate

You need to add your second activity on your manifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".SecondScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

Comment: I have added that into the manifest, well not the label - what is the label for please?

Comment: just look at your res/values/string for the app_name

Answer (score 0):

adding to previous answers:
you can create button in your xml layout as much as you want, this doesn't have relation with the oncreate method.

all you have to do to use these button in your mainactivity java file is to initialize it like this:

```
 Button name=(Button)findViewById(R.id."button name or id in your xml file");
```

you can press "Ctrl plus space" in the same time after "R.id." to get you all the objects you have created in the xml file and choose what you want.
no to switch to another activity do this in your onclicklistener.

```
       startActivity(new Intent("yourcurrent activity".this, "the name of activity you want to switch to".class));
```

which in this case is:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondScreen.class));
```

then go to you AndroidManifest file and type this inside the application part...you can type it at the very end of the application part.

```
  <activity android:name=".the name of your second activity"/>
```

which in your case is:

```
 <activity android:name=".Secondscreen"/>
```

you have to do this whenever creating a new activity.

then in your second activity you should tell what xml file you are viewing so you should do this in the second class activity, just like default of the mainacitivty once you have created it.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout."name of your xml file you want to view");
```

and i suggest you have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6-4E1JGT_k